# Unable to spin up AD Forest by ARM Template

Tags: azure, active-directory, azure-rm-template

I am trying to create a Windows VM, AD Forest, Domain and DC by ARM Templates.

I am using template from here:

```
https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/tree/master/active-directory-new-domain
```

I created resource group and then deployment by the below commands:

```
az group create --name arm-template --location "australiaeast"
az group deployment create -g arm-template --template-file=azuredeploy.json --parameters=azuredeploy.parameters.json
```

Unfortunately, I am getting the error below:

```
400 Client Error: Bad Request for url: https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/resourcegroups/arm-template/providers/Microsoft.Resources/deployments/azuredeploy?api-version=2018-05-01
```

I am able to create them Manually by Going to Azure Portal by using exact same parameters! wondering what is the issue and how to resolve it.

P. S: Edit, Using template-file does not work. Evidence below:

```
PS E:\OnlyOnMyPC\azure-quickstart-templates\active-directory-new-domain> New-AzResourceGroupDeployment -ResourceGroupName arm-template
 -TemplateFile azuredeploy.json -TemplateParameterFile .\azuredeploy.parameters.json
New-AzResourceGroupDeployment : 5:27:27 PM - Error: Code=InvalidTemplate; Message=Deployment template validation failed: 'The
template resource '_artifactsLocation' at line '37' and column '31' is not valid: The language expression property 'templateLink'
doesn't exist, available properties are 'template, templateHash, parameters, mode, provisioningState'.. Please see
https://aka.ms/arm-template-expressions for usage details.'.
At line:1 char:1
+ New-AzResourceGroupDeployment -ResourceGroupName arm-template -Templa ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [New-AzResourceGroupDeployment], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Azure.Commands.ResourceManager.Cmdlets.Implementation.NewAzureResourceGroupDeploymentCmdlet

New-AzResourceGroupDeployment : The deployment validation failed
At line:1 char:1
+ New-AzResourceGroupDeployment -ResourceGroupName arm-template -Templa ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (:) [New-AzResourceGroupDeployment], InvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Azure.Commands.ResourceManager.Cmdlets.Implementation.NewAzureResourceGroupDeploymentCmdlet
```

Comment: try the same using the cloudshell, i suspect something fishy with your azcli

Comment: Tried with cloudshell same error. Tried with --verbose but it provides no value.

Comment: try with powershell?

Comment: Yes tried with PowerShell and realized that it needs Template-url so local file won't do

Comment: thats nonsense, you can use local file

Comment: Ok, fine, I might be wrong, how to use local file? Can you give me command? I tried with template-file and it does not work. In fact I am eager to know how it would work with template-file. Appreciate your guidance.

Comment: `New-AzResourceGroupDeployment -ResourceGroupName xxx -TemplateFile yyy -TemplateParameterFile zzz`

Comment: this is not related to powershell not being able to pass in template\parameters file from the local disk, read the error and read your answer

Answer (score 0):

The way I got working is by the below command:

```
az group deployment create -g arm-template --template-uri "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/master/active-directory-new-domain/azuredeploy.json" --parameters @azuredeploy.parameters.json
```

The reason for that is azuredeploy.json uses **templateLink.uri**. It is unfortunate though as where Security is the concern you will have to use Storage account to upload the file and refer it in your template.

More reading [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-linked-templates)

Now, it is also important to understand what made me realize is I used  **Azure PowerShell** instead of *Azure Cli*, it reports better error message that just HTTP 400.